Push Notifications Stats
I am using Firebase Push Notifications using Topics.
Is there any way to know if app received notification while in background or how can I know which user has received notifications and which not (basically a report).
I already know about Firebase console report but that is general report. I wanted to know if there is another way around.
Want to know exact data of users who received notifications through topic.

The delivery reporting options for Firebase Cloud Messaging are what you already found in the Firebase console, the aggregated delivery data, and the optional BigQuery export. The latter is probably closest to what you want, just be sure to enable message delivery data export for your platform(s) of choice.
If none of these options work for your needs, you'll have to roll your own implementation.

Can we add our custom data to BigQuery like userId or It will also tell us generic data?

You can't add your own data directly to the FCM export, as that would never scale to the levels that FCM needs to support. But you can of course add your own tables with such information, e.g. by storing the message ID and user ID when you call the send API.
